# Xamarin Forms UriImageSource with TLS 1.2 and Android <20

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tls1.2

I have a Xamarin Forms app that needs to run on Android <20 and load content from a TLS1.2 server. 
Following the example in [this blog](https://sviluppomobile.blogspot.it/2017/06/enable-tls-12-11-xamarinandroid.html) I was able to get most of my content working, but I still have an issue with images.  I can get them to work if I manually download them using HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() and ImageSource.FromStream, but it is very slow and doesn't support caching.

What I really want to do is provide a custom SSLSocketFactory / AndroidClentHandler for the connection used by Image. Is there a way to change the default that Xamarin uses behind the scenes?